# NVD3 stacked area chart - xAxis date and Tooltip date formatting

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I thought that the interactiveGuideline header date format would inherit the same xAxis tick format, but I'm having some trouble making these line up.

I'd like both to have d3.time.format('%b-%y') however after I set the xAxis tickFormat to %b-%y, the tooltip provides a different date in terms of the year.

I tried customizing the tooltip header which only works if I set the original xAxis tickFormat to d3.time.format('%x') first.  I'm relatively new to this so I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.  I appreciate any help on this.

Here is the code and the JSfiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/timothymartin76/vmg75kzb/2/

```
        var histcatexplong = [
    {
        "key" : "Fully Automated" ,
        "values" : [ [ 1406937600000 , 4905] , 
        [ 1409616000000 , 4583] , 
        [ 1412208000000 , 5276] , 
        [ 1414886400000 , 6300] , 
        [ 1417478400000 , 4684] , 
        [ 1420156800000 , 15129] , 
        [ 1422835200000 , 11186] , 
        [ 1425254400000 , 8555] , 
        [ 1427932800000 , 4866] , 
        [ 1430524800000 , 6080] , 
        [ 1433203200000 , 5729] , 
        [ 1435795200000 , 5467] , 
        [ 1438473600000 , 3800] , 
        [ 1441152000000 , 4345]]
    } ,

     {
        "key" : "Partially Automated" ,
        "values" : [ [ 1406937600000 , 638] , 
        [ 1409616000000 , 379] , 
        [ 1412208000000 , 684] , 
        [ 1414886400000 , 934] , 
        [ 1417478400000 , 509] , 
        [ 1420156800000 , 399] , 
        [ 1422835200000 , 329] , 
        [ 1425254400000 , 340] , 
        [ 1427932800000 , 0] , 
        [ 1430524800000 , 0] , 
        [ 1433203200000 , 0] , 
        [ 1435795200000 , 0] , 
        [ 1438473600000 , 0] , 
        [ 1441152000000 , 0]]
    } ,

     {
        "key" : "Fully Aided" ,
        "values" : [ [ 1406937600000 , 5018] , 
        [ 1409616000000 , 4848] , 
        [ 1412208000000 , 5441] , 
        [ 1414886400000 , 6822] , 
        [ 1417478400000 , 5353] , 
        [ 1420156800000 , 14625] , 
        [ 1422835200000 , 11084] , 
        [ 1425254400000 , 8812] , 
        [ 1427932800000 , 5855] , 
        [ 1430524800000 , 7245] , 
        [ 1433203200000 , 7505] , 
        [ 1435795200000 , 8417] , 
        [ 1438473600000 , 6245] , 
        [ 1441152000000 , 6312]]


    }
];

var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
        .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
        .controlLabels({stacked: "Stacked"})
        //.yDomain([0,35000])
        .duration(300);


    chart.xAxis
        .ticks(12)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b-%y')(new Date(d)) });

    chart.xScale(d3.time.scale());  


    chart.yAxis
        .ticks(8)
        .tickFormat(d3.format(','));

        //Example of how to customize the tooltip.
    chart.interactiveLayer
        .tooltip
        .headerFormatter(function(d) {return "Date: " + d3.time.format('%b-%y')(new Date(d));})
        //.valueFormatter(d3.format(',.2f'));

    chart.legend.vers('furious');

    d3.select('#chart1')
        .datum(histcatexplong)
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .call(chart)
        .each('start', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                d3.selectAll('#chart1 *').each(function() {
                    if(this.__transition__)
                        this.__transition__.duration = 1;
                })
            }, 0)
        });

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);    
    return chart;
});
```